# Using new WP_Query in shortcode in a custom field causes the main post content to not display

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, wp-query, loop

I've got a custom post type of files I'm trying to list using a new WP_Query.

It works fine when I add the shortcode within the main post content. However, when I add the shortcode to a custom field (which I have set to display on the page along with the main content as a secondary "column"), the main content disappears!

If I comment out the "while...have_posts()" and "endwhile" lines, the main content displays; however, even after commenting out every other line, the main content disappears unless I also remove the "while".

I am pretty certain it has to do with using WP_Query (somehow it hijacks the loop), even though it shouldn't.

Is there something I'm missing?

Here's the shortcode:

```
   function ia_news_display_test($atts){ // [ia_news cat='category' num='numbertodisplay']

extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'cat' => 'any',
        'num' => '2',
        ), $atts));

$dirloop = new wp_query( array( 
    'post_type' => 'ia_news', 
    'category_name' => $cat,
    'posts_per_page' => $num,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC'
));

if ($dirloop->have_posts()){
    $content = "<ul class='ia_news_list'>\n";
    while ( $dirloop->have_posts() ) : $dirloop->the_post();
        $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
        $file_id = $custom["upload_file"][0];
        $file_begin = $custom["begin_date"][0];
        $file_end = $custom["end_date"][0];
        if ('' != $file_end){$file_end = " to ".$file_end;}
        $file_url = wp_get_attachment_url($file_id);

            if ('' != $file_url) { //CHECK FOR EXISTENCE OF FILE URL
               $content .= "<li class='ia_nl'><a href='".$file_url."'>".$cat." ".$file_begin.$file_end."</a></li>\n";
            }
    endwhile;
    $content .= "</ul>\n";
} else { $content = "nothing"; }

return $content;
```

}

Comment: Edited with the actual code I was attempting to use...sheesh!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `get_posts` which returns an array of posts, which you can loop through using `foreach`, but not `the_loop`. Try this version of the code:

```
function ia_news_display_test($atts){ // [ia_news cat='category' num='numbertodisplay']

extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'cat' => 'any',
        'num' => '2',
        ), $atts));

$dirloop = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type' => 'ia_news', 
    'category_name' => $cat,
    'posts_per_page' => $num,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC'
));

    if ($dirloop->have_posts())
    {
        $content = "<ul class='ia_news_list'>\n";
        while ( $dirloop->have_posts() ) : $dirloop->the_post();

            $file_id = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), "upload_file", true);
            $file_begin = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), "begin_date", true);
            $file_end = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), "end_date", true);

            if ('' != $file_end)
            {
                $file_end = " to ".$file_end;
            }
            $file_url = wp_get_attachment_url($file_id);

            if ('' != $file_url) 
            {   
                //CHECK FOR EXISTENCE OF FILE URL
                $content .= "<li class='ia_nl'><a href='".$file_url."'>".$cat." ".$file_begin.$file_end."</a></li>\n";
            }
        endwhile;
        $content .= "</ul>\n";
    } 
    else
    { 
        $content = "nothing";
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();

    return $content;
}

add_shortcode('ia_news_test', 'ia_news_display_test');
```

Also, if you're custom field name is `upload_file`, then try using `get_post_meta` instead of taking a long cut as you're code does.

Comment: YIKES! I was tired and put in the version of the code I was playing around with.

I actually was using WP_Query, which caused the problem (I believe), so I was starting to use the get_posts function.

I'll try to paste in your version to see what happens.

Comment: SWEET! I wonder if it was using get_post_meta...it appears that was all that was really changed from my original code.

You're the bomb. I'd give you a bump up if I could ^^

Comment: :) Still learning :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `wp_reset_postdata()` before you return out of the function. Similar to `wp_reset_query()`, but restores the global `$post` instead of `$wp_the_query`.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use [`wp_reset_query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query) after the loop. That should reset your query. Let me know it works or not.

Comment: The author’s code doesn’t change the main query. Why should a reset do anything useful?

Comment: +1 @toscho. If he was using `query_posts`, `wp_reset_query()` was the solution.

Comment: I believe this is true using new wp_query as well, since it sets up a separate loop, correct? In any case, I had already tried this (just to be certain) with no success.